# Separating Identifiers from keywords in flex scanning

Tags: flex-lexer

I am using flex to generate tokens from a declaration statement as:

```
int a = 5;
```

Tokens are:

```
<int> <id,a> <=> <5>
```

note that lexeme for int is int and a is lexeme for the token id.

Coming to lex code:

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE char*
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int lineno=1;
%}

white [ \t]+
letter [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]
id {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
number {digit}+
relop >=|<=|>|<|==|!=


%% 

{white} { }

{number} {yylval=strdup(yytext); return NUMBER;}
{id} { yylval=strdup(yytext); return ID;}
"+" return PLUS;
"-" return MINUS;
"*" return TIMES;
"/" return DIVIDE;
int return INT;
float return FLOAT;
```

The problem is the strings int and float are being matched as ID and the token is returned as ID. Consequently there is a syntax error. Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the int/float lines first, the order you list them is the order matched.

The rule letter(letter|number)* will match any sequence of one of more letters, put float above it and float will match before it tries letter(letter|number)

By first I mean "anywhere above ID, still in the definitions section"